# scala pattern matching in actor class

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, actor

I have this akka actor:

```
class Counter2 extends Actor {

  def counter(n:Int):Receive = {
    case "incr" => context.become(counter(n+1))
    case "get" => sender ! n
  }

  def receive = counter(0)
}
```

The `counter` function performs pattern matching against the value that is received by the `receive` function.

How can the `counter()` "know" that the pattern matching has to be done with the values received by `receive`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of the method `receive` is of type `Receive` which is an alias for `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`. Thus, the incoming actor messages are not given to `receive` but Akka calls `receive` to obtain the messaging function. This function is then applied to the incoming messages. In your case the partial function is defined by `counter(n: Int)`, a function which is instantiated with a specific value for `n`.